# Redirigir a una web depediendo de la url javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando redirigir una web.

Cuento lo que quiero hacer. Tengo una web, y quiero redirigirla a una página u otra dependiendo de la url que aparezca en la barra de navegación

Si aparece la palabra null, que me redirija a una url y si aparece la palabra personal, me redirija a otra url.

Y no doy con la manera de introducir esas cadenas en una variable, para introducirlas en el bucle.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
       var myrpstatus = new Object();
        var lastURL = window.location.href.indexOf('null);

     window.onload = function (){
           j.ajax({
               url: "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/do/make/rp/myRp.json?action=status",
               success: function (data) {
                   myrpstatus = data.myrp;
                   if( lastURL){
                    window.location.replace("<%= request.getContextPath() %>"+ myrpstatus.url);

                   }else{

                       window.location.replace(<%= request.getContextPath() %>" + "/dos");
                   }
               }
           });
       };
```

¿Alguna idea?
Saludos
Gonzalo

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema lo tienes en tu condicional `if(lastURL)`, asumes erróneamente que el método `indexOf()` devolverá algo que puedes usar en tu condicional de la forma que crees.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla. Leyendo la documentación de [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf):

> El método `indexOf()` devuelve el índice, dentro del objeto `String` que realiza la llamada, de la primera ocurrencia del valor especificado, comenzando la búsqueda desde `indiceDesde`; o -1 si no se encuentra dicho valor.
>
> ## *Sintaxis*
>
> `cadena.indexOf(valorBusqueda[, indiceDesde])`

Entonces, `lastURL` contendrá el índice de la ocurrencia de la cadena `"null"` ( es lo que pasas como argumento), además la búsqueda empezará en el índice `0` ya que no pasas un valor de `indiceDesde`.

Si la cadena `"null"` no se encuentra, entonces `lastURL` tendrá un valor de `-1`, indicando que la cadena no fue encontrada.

Cuando haces `if(lastURL)` la condición siempre devolverá `true` a menos que `lastURL` sea cero.

**¿Porqué?**

Sencillamente porque en Javascript existen valores considerados [*truthy* o *falsey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Esto quiere decir que un valor se considera `true` o `false` cuando es evaluado en un contexto de operación booleana. Por ejemplo, cuando haces `if(lastURL)` estás realizando una evaluación del valor de `lastURL` en un contexto booleano (`if` es un condicional que evalúa valores booleanos).

Debido a que el valor de `lastURL` será un entero mayor o igual a `-1`, el único caso en que dicho valor será considerado como `false` es cuando vale `0`. Pero un valor de `0` en dicha variable indica que la cadena `"null"` fue hallada a partir del primer índice de la cadena evaluada. Por lo tanto, la evaluación condicional que estás haciendo no es la adecuada.

Tu condición por ende debe ser reescrita como

```
if(lastURL < 0) {
    // realizo operaciones si "null" no es parte de la URL
} else {
    // realizo operaciones si "null" se encuentra en la URL
}
```

Como puedes ver, estamos evaluando el caso en que el valor de `lastURL` es menor que cero. Como vimos anteriormente, esto ocurre sólo si la cadena `"null"` no es hallada en la `url` sobre la que realizamos la búsqueda.

Con esto tu problema debería estar resuelto.

Un ejemplo de la solución:

```js
let url = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264699/redirigir-a-una-web-depediendo-de-la-url-javascript';

let lastURL = url.indexOf('null');

console.log('El valor de lastURL es: ', lastURL);

//Usando tu código:

if(lastURL) {
    console.log('¿Porque se imprime esto si no existe "null" en la url?');
}

//Usando la solución

if(lastURL < 0) {
    console.log('La url no contiene la cadena "null"');
} else {
    console.log('Se encontró "null" en la cadena');
}
```